# I am confused on how to solve this question about one way hashing

Tags: hash, one-way-function

[image]

I know that I have to use decryption, but I am confused about how it breaks one-way (preimage resistance)

Comment: @kelalaka They are supposed to break one-wayness, not collision resistance. Hint: What happens if you simply decrypt with IV?

Comment: @Maeher Oh, why did I miss this. Yes, the IV and the hash value is key. Thanks. The otherwise quite complicated to do as homework.